# Как сделать маску на регулярных выражениях для поиска слова в " "?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно найти слово в " ", например "Example", слово всегда в двойных кавычках и содержит только буквы без знаков. Нужно составить регулярное выражение для поиска.

Comment: Вроде бы так `/"([^"]+)"/`

Comment: Да, работает, это работает тоже: "[A-Za-z]+"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так/"([^"]+)"/ или так "[A-Za-z]+"